# How do you update Grid Cell Binding Converters manually?

Tags: c#, wpf, ivalueconverter

I am currently using a Grid that allows for row virtualisation however one of the cells is bound to a List(Observable) Object which has an attached IValueConverter that modifies the list into some sort of string. If i update the values in the List they aren't reflected in the grid until the Items have left the screen(scrolled out of view) and then redisplayed. Is there a way to update the Value Converter manually?

Or would it be better create a readonly string to display the list in Comma seperated. What would be the best way to notify the UI that the List has changed and update the readonly string value in my grid?

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Have u implemented INotifyPropertyChanged Interface on your class whose list u r making in List(Observable) Object

[More on this topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible for me to have an ObservableCollection as a property in a class but subscribe to the CollectionChanged event and call  OnPropertyChanged on the ObservableCollection property?